# I wanna fetch my blogposts from my website, to my iOS app. What knowledge is required to do this?

Tags: ios

My website is up and running with support from Wix.com, I used the drag and drop builder to set it up and I didn't need to do any Client side/Server side programming for it to work.

What should I do if I want to keep the app updated with the website as soon as I upload any article/post on the website.

Answer (score 1):

Consider taking a different approach and migrate to a platform/architecture that better suits your specific case.

My suggestion would be [Microweber](https://microweber.com) - it's a pretty advanced platform for websites with CMS and e-commerce [features](https://microweber.com/features). It's been around for quite some time (3 years or so) and I'm using it for about 12 live active projects.

It's very neat if you plan to write custom code as it's based on Laravel and everything is easily extendable.
However, I'm using it mainly because of the support. Although it's free and open-source the team is online most of the time and have replied to my every request so far.

This is critical for me as many website solutions come and go and none is 
perfect. What makes this one better is the reaction time and adequacy.

This is my personal opinion with regard to the fact that it's very hard to pick one solution among so many given that you didn't state more specific requirements.

Answer (score 0):

It cannot be done without any server side scripting and backend database for the mobile app. you  need to develop database for it.and then you will need to develop web service for the passing the data between mobile and backend.

Answer (score 0):

A dirty way to do this would be through an HTTP request that reads HTML. However the best way would be through Wix's REST API.

Edit: I'm regards to keeping the app updated, you're going to need a backend service that is consistently checking for updates.